# How to show average from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to show the average of a column in mysql?

**Below is my code which i have tried so far :**

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET["age"]));
  $age = ($_GET["age"]);
  include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/config.php");

  // Input
  $sql = "SELECT AVG(column_name) FROM table_name";

  // Check age
  if ($age > 99 or $age < 5) {
    echo ("We only store data of people between the age of 5 and 99.");
    if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
    }
  } 
  else {
    echo ("We got it!");
  }

  // Close connection
  ((is_null($___mysqli_res = mysqli_close($conn))) ? false : $___mysqli_res);

  die();
?>
```

But how to exactly define a variable to the result of the AVG with a maximum of 2 decimals?

I want to used and show it into another file (so I will include this one).

**What I have right now**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["age"]));
$age = ($_GET["age"]);
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/3/includes/config.php");
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/3/includes/opendb.php");

// My own created code
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT ROUND(AVG(price AS FLOAT), 2) FROM data WHERE age= '$age'");
$data = $sql->mysqli_fetch_assoc();
$avg_data = $data['price'];
echo $avg_data;

// This below is from an other post but don't know how it works and if it is good.
$ratings = $conn->query("SELECT AVG(price) avg_rating FROM data form_id = '" . $age . "'");
$data2 = $ratings->mysqli_fetch_assoc();
$avg_rating = $data2['avg_rating'];
echo $avg_rating;

die();

?>
```

Comment: You are only executing the query but never fetching the result.

Comment: `ROUND(AVG(column_name), 2)`?

Comment: where is the code to fetch the data ???

Comment: How to make that? I am a 'noob' at mysqli @MehulKuriya I did some research but I don't know how to make it.

Comment: How to do that? @Daan

Comment: @WalkingForNepal Every PHP+MySQL tutorial should show how to call `mysqli_fetch_array` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to fetch the result. If you've never seen that, then you didn't do any real research.

Comment: It looks like your code is the result of a converter from `mysql` to `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How I fixed it:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["age"])) {
$age = ($_GET["age"]);

include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/3/includes/config.php");

$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT AVG(price) FROM data WHERE age= '$age'") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['AVG(price)'];
   echo number_format($row['AVG(price)'], 2);
}

die();
}
else {
echo 'Something went wrong, try again.';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Like This For Getting Average witth two decimal points.

```
  $sql = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(column_name AS FLOAT), 2) FROM table_name";
```

Comment: Allright, and how to bind that to an variable, so I can echo it out? Check the end of my question for the code that I have right now.

Comment: Bind That In Variable Means ?? What You Want To Do Now??

Comment: Well, I want to fetch it so I can echo the result.

Comment: I tried something else too, but I didn't got any errors, but it is not echoing something out too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT *, ROUND(AVG(column_name), 2) AS avg_value FROM table_name';
```

`avg_value` will store the rounded + average value and add `*` if need to get all the column.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Ok. I will try read more how other people post and learn it. Thanks for the advise :).